# Adaptive payment plug in integrated in front end to split payments through paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently developing a site for users to donate money to the respective NGO. The % of payment(which will be assigned by admin) will go to the paypal ID of the respective user and the other part will go to the other user.

How can I customise adaptive payment to code this function in the front end??

Answer (score 0):

Paypal Adopative payment process is very simple. First you need to register with developer account. Then you need to create one demo application on paypal website. Use UserId, password and demo paypal appId(APP-80W284485P519543T) in you code.

Set your return, cancel and IPN url.

Here is the flow.

let me know if you want any more help.

[Click here to see more information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/)